# Condition for using binomial theorem for negative index

Tags: binomial-theorem

Prove that $(x^2 + \frac{1}{x})^{-4/3}$ can be expanded by binomial theorem if $|x|>1$.

Now I know that $(1+x)^n$ can be expanded for negative index if $|x|<1$.

How should I prove it here?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**
Assuming $x \ne 0$,

$$
\left(x^2+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{-4/3} = x^{-8/3} \left(1 + \frac{1}{x^3}\right)^{4/3}
$$

Comment: The exponent should be -4/3, not 4/3.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Any exponent will do. See the generalized binomial theorem.

Comment: @Adam corrected

Comment: @gt6989b What if instead of taking $x^2$ common , we take $1/x$ common? The condition would reverse?

Comment: @Mathematics honestly not sure, spent time thinking about it when was writing the answer -- the only difference is the leading factor would have positive power, not sure if this would make a difference right now. sorry to be of no help

Answer (score 0):

$$(x^2 + \frac{1}{x})^{-4/3} = [x^2(1+\frac{1}{x^3})]^{-4/3} = x^{-8/3}(1+x^{-3})^{-4/3} $$

$x^{-8/3}$ is just a factor, so we can ignore it. Imposing the conditions you quote ($n < 0$ and $|x| < 1$), the expansion is valid if $-\frac{4}{3} < 0$ and $|x^{-3}| < 1$. Now clearly the former is true, but we need to work out what values of $x$ satisfies the latter.

$$ |\frac{1}{x^3}| < 1 \implies 1 < |x^3|$$

If $|x| \le 1$ then $|x^3| \le 1$, which does not satisfy our criterion.

If $|x| > 1$ then $|x^3| > 1$, so this is the range for which the expansion is valid.

Comment: What if instead of taking $x^2$ common , we take $1/x$ common? The condition would reverse?